# Image wrapping. How to keep on one line

Tags: css

I have the following code but the image is wrapping below the input box. What am I doing wrong?

```
<input type=text name='test" />
<div style="float:left"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: `name='test"` opens with a single quote but closes with a double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this instead.

```
<input type="text" name="test" style="float:left" />
<div><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
```

It also works just as well if you remove the `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

the `<div>` tag it's a *block*, it mean have a *new line* before and after, try to use a `<span>`

```
<span ><img src="test.jpg" /></span>
```

Comment: Or just drop the span and leave the `img` there alone. Also, the correct term is "block level element". The `div` is not a "block" ;)

Comment: maybe yes, i guess the div it's there for a reason... i hope :)

Answer (score 0):

Your div is floated left from the point at which it would normally appear in the source order, ie on a new line below the input. Try floating the input as well.

Comment: Thanks Chris, floating the input was what did the trick for me. Thanks.